# Trying to parse a pdf in PERL and the output seems to have problems

Tags: perl, pdf

I tried parsing the following file in PERL using CAM::PDF

http://www.roehampton.ac.uk/uploadedFiles/Pages_Assets/PDFs_and_Word_Docs/Human_Resources/VL%20Advert%20Biomedical%20Sciences%20Sep%2012.pdf

But I seem to be getting a lot of newlines than I see when I open the PDF.
Here is a snapshot of my sample code.

```
        my $file_name = 'file_3.pdf';
        my $filecontent;
        my @lines = '';
        my $save = "/home/tejas/Projects/Richmond/pdf/";
        $file_name = $save . $file_name;
        my $doc = CAM::PDF->new($file_name) || die "$CAM::PDF::errstr\n";

foreach my $p ( 1 .. $doc->numPages() ) {
    my $str = $doc->getPageText($p);
    if (defined $str) {
       CAM::PDF->asciify(\$str);
       print  $str;
    }
}
```

I have downloaded and stored the pdf from the link to file_3.pdf.
Please let me know if there is anything better I can do while parsing to stictch some lines together (especially the ones which are broken in the middle of the word).

Comment: I got exactly the same output with PDF::OCR2. Can you use a non perl solution ? pdftotext (from xpdf distribution) with `-layout` option do a very good job.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this little script:

```
$ perl -MCAM::PDF -Mstrict - ~/Downloads/perldata.pdf 
my $doc = CAM::PDF->new($ARGV[0]) or die;
my $str = $doc->getPageText(1);
CAM::PDF->asciify(\$str);
my @blocks = split /\n\s*\n\s*\n/, $str;
foreach (@blocks) {
  $_=~ s/\s*\n\s*/ /g;
  print $_, "\n\n";
}
__END__
```

I split the file into blocks or paragraphs at consecutive empty lines. Then, I remove all newlines (with surrounding spaces) inside this paragraph. If we replace it with a space (as I did above), we get weird spaces. If we use the regex `s/\n//g` instead, some words are run together where there should be spaces. But both possibilities are quite readable nevertheless, try it out.

It is not easily posible to get an ideal solution. Keep in mind that the PDF format is all about the graphical representation of documents and not about semantics.

The first few lines look like this:

```
Department of Life Sciences

Visiting Lecturer s (1.5 FTE) in B iomedical S cience s

The popularity [...]
```